# How to hide closed questions when searching for questions to answer

Tags: support

It seems many of the questions here end up closed. Having most of my searches consist largely of closed questions makes finding questions I can answer even harder and more tedious. (Rarely will will a title tell me if I can answer a question or not. I need to know the details inside)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the [site search](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search), you can search for *questions* with the `is:q` operator and for non-closed questions with `closed:no`: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano

By itself, that isn't really useful, but of course you can add tags (e.g. `[biology]`) or other search terms in the mix.

Comment: Seems weird that you can only do that with the site search, and there is no way to do it with the main page filtering and sorting options

Comment: Well, we do have an [unanswered tab](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) which doesn't contain closed questions. But that severely limits your options...

Comment: [There is a feature request for adding "not closed" for custom filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355243/add-option-not-closed-to-the-custom-filters). This can make them potentially viable for finding questions to answer. Right now the best you can do is "no accepted answers" but IMO that doesn't mean that you cannot write an answer yourself. To be truly useful, though, it probably also needs a "not mine" filter [but the FR for this was declined on technical complexity reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330356/)